# How to define the parton distribution function of the antiquark?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

So I can define the quark distribution function within a hadron as
$$
f_{\psi/h}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dz^-}{2\pi}e^{ixP^+z^-}
\langle h(p)|\bar{\psi}(0)\gamma^+\psi(z^-)|h(p)\rangle|_{z^2=0}
$$
where $a^{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a^0 \pm a^3)$, and where $A^+=0$.
This can be constructed from the lower half of the handbag diagram shown below.

To construct the antiquark distribution I imagine all I would need to do is reverse the
direction of the fermion lines, leaving me with

$$
f_{\bar{\psi}/h}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dz^-}{2\pi}e^{ixP^+z^-}
\langle h(p)|\psi(0)\gamma^+\bar{\psi}(z^-)|h(p)\rangle|_{z^2=0}
$$

Is this correct?

[image]