# How to derive quark-antiquark parton distribution relation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

This is kind of similar to this post here [How to define the parton distribution function of the antiquark?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/557832/) with no response.

I basically want to derive the following; $f_q(x) = -f_{\bar{q}}(-x)$ where

- $f_q(x)$: quark distribution function with momentum fraction x
- $f_{\bar{q}}(x)$: anti-quark distribution function with momentum fraction x

My guess on how to derive this is so simple, I think there has got to be something wrong with it. Line by line it goes as (in Axial Gauge, $A^+(z) = 0$)

$$
f_q(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dz^-}{2\pi}e^{ixp^+z^-}\langle h(p)|\bar{q}(-z/2)\gamma^+q(z/2)|h(p)\rangle \\
= -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dz^-}{2\pi} e^{ixp^+z^-}\langle h(p)|\text{Tr}\big[\gamma^+q(z/2)\bar{q}(-z/2) \big]|h(p)\rangle \; \text{: Fermion permutation} \\
= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dz^-}{2\pi} e^{-ixp^+z^-}\langle h(p)|\text{Tr}\big[\gamma^+q(-z/2)\bar{q}(z/2) \big]|h(p)\rangle  \; : z\rightarrow -z \\
= f_{\bar{q}}(-x)
$$
Clearly this is wrong as there is no longer an over-all minus sign. My definition for the antiquark distribution is just wrong. So how do I get to the correct answer?

Comment: maybe this will help https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9609018

Comment: @CosmasZachos Maybe you are more comfortable with computing something like $\int_0^1 dx(f_q(x) - f_{\bar{q}}(x))$. In the integrand you are adding $-f_{\bar{q}}(x)$. Under the relation I am trying to derive, what we have is effectively $\int_0^1 dx(f_q(x) + f_q(-x)) = \int_{-1}^1 dx f_q(x)$. You can think of this as a redefinition of the quark distribution function that combines quark and anti-quark distributions within the domain $x \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: Indeed, I am. I had actually never seen the negative *x* convention.